# How can I display path on right side of terminal screen instead of before prompt?

Tags: bash, terminal, path, prompt

I'd like to show the current working directory on the right side of screen in bash terminal and no path before the prompt where it is shown now.

Ubuntu 18.04 LTS

Comment: Should it be in the same line? Or can it be in the line above (multiline prompt)? What is your research effort? What have you tried so far? Closely related: [*Right align part of prompt*](https://superuser.com/q/187455/432690).

Comment: Yes. Same line. I've delved far and wide with nothing for what I'm looking for.
My instructor has his prompt on the left of course but it's just user name. At the end (right screen) of that same line is the current path.

Comment: How about asking the instructor then? Are you sure it's bash? Zsh does support this, I think (research `RPROMPT`).

Comment: ubuntu 18.04 terminal. I read all of the "closely related" and it all mainly puts a second line or useless data on the right. It's a Bootcamp. I asked instructor and he told me he'd show me in a minute then never did. It's so fast-paced in class that interruptions aren't too welcome. 
I may be able to play with some of the "closely related" scripts I saw and get ${PATH} in there somehow.